# Direction of current when there are 2+ batteries on circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, voltage, conventions, batteries

By the conventional direction, current points from + to -. But what happens when there are more than one batteries on the circuit,with the battery poles connected to each other with any combination?

An image example would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please be more specific and add the image you are interested in.

Comment: Here's an image (the first): https://www.google.com/search?q=circuit+with+more+than+one+battery&sxsrf=ACYBGNT0mBNiXOYV_5Oaqd-QkwZbJC2ySQ:1577693493321&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCke-h9tzmAhURjqQKHZNtBCkQ_AUoAXoECA0QAw&biw=1536&bih=722#imgrc=TpaoNo9cbZ8FYM&imgdii=6kr3V_jJ8F8UiM

Comment: What is the logic behind it?If current goes from + to - then shouldn't it stop as soon as it encounters the first negative pole?

Comment: @Some1 please note that in the battery itself, charges will go from negative to positive pole! That's, battery uses chemical energy to do that. In circuit itself however, charges will go from positive to negative easily.

Answer (score 2):

It's completely arbitrary. Just choose a direction you want. After using Kirchhoff's voltage law and Kirchoff's current law, if current becomes negative, that'd mean direction of current is opposite, else your primary choice is correct.

However, if you don't know Kirchhoff laws, you can assume that the direction of current will be determined by the most powerful source. Of course, it's not always the case, but in simple circuits (like the one with two batteries), it surely is. If you had several sources, more than 3, you should consider all batteries with same poles together, until you get two sources with opposite poles, and again you can use the same logic for circuit. But I will suggest learning Kirchhoff laws. They are very simple, and at the same time powerful.

Comment: To add to this, the more powerful battery may get discharged while the less powerful one gets charged.